# C# to VB.NET array initialization

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays

In C#, I can *declare* an array variable like this

```
object[] Parameters;
```

and *initialize* it like this:

```
Parameters = new object[20];
```

In Visual Basic, *declaring and initializing* an array is easy:

```
Dim Parameters(19) As Object
Dim Parameters As Object(19)    ' Alternative syntax
```

How would I initialize an array variable *that has already been declared* in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

`Parameters = New Object(19)` doesn't work.

---

For example, how would I translate the following to VB.NET?

```
int value = 20;
object[] Parameters;
if (value > 10)
{
    Parameters = new Object[20];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the same Visual Basic code as the others, but I'd use the opportunity to add a bit of style:

```vb
Dim value = 20                ' Type inference, like "var" in C#
Dim parameters() As Object    ' Could also be "parameters As Object()"
If value > 10 Then
    parameters = New Object(19) {}   ' That's right, Visual Basic uses the maximum index
End If                               ' instead of the number of elements.
```

Local variables (`parameters`) should start with a lowercase letter. It's an established convention and it helps to get correct syntax highlighting in Stack Overflow (this also applies to the original C# code).

So, why are the braces `{}` required in Visual Basic? In Visual Basic, both method calls and array access use parenthesis `(...)`. Thus, `New X(4)` could mean:

- Create a new object of type `X` and pass `4` to the constructor,
- Create a 5-element [sic] array of `X`.

To distinguish the two cases, you use the array initializer syntax in the second case. Usually, the braces contain actual values:

```
myArray = New Integer() {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim value As Integer = 20
Dim Parameters() as object
If value > 10 then
  Parameters = new Object(value - 1){}
end if
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are lazy like me you could use an [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) which yields:

```
Dim value As Integer = 20
Dim Parameters As Object()
If value > 10 Then
    Parameters = New [Object](19) {}
End If
```

And if you are not like me and want to learn VB.NET head over to the documentation of the VB.NET syntax and start reading.

Comment: If you've programmed in VB.NET for any length of time, you may consider replacing the constant 19 with (value - 1).  Will save you some headache/time if value variables value changes.  That's the problem with online converters.

Comment: @CommonSense, luckily I had never had to use this language in my programming career. And when occasions presented, I simply rewrote the code to C# as I just can't stand VB.NET.